# How to identify the assigned roles for a user in MS graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

There are 2 ways to assign a role (Ex: Global Administrator) to a user

1. Directly adding the role to the user.
2. Add the user to a group and assign the role to that group

Now I want to know whether the user is assigned with Global Administrator role or not. If I use **memberOf** api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it is returning me "Global Administrator" permission only if it is directly assigned to the user. But if it is indirectly assigned to the user via a group, I am not able to see that.

There is another api which i saw - **transitiveRoleAssignments** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-transitiveroleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) . This is solving the problem. But since this is a beta API, i cannot use this.

Is there any other way where I can fetch the roles assigned to the user (including indirect assignment through groups)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [transitiveMemberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which returns nested groups and directory assignments, and this isn't in beta

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/transitiveMemberOf
```

Comment: As a followup on this, I need to list down all the global admins. I tried using this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. But this is not returning admins via group. Is there any other api for it?

Comment: @deepakasai There doesn't seem to be an API available for that